# moving files from many directories into one

Tags: filesystems, extract

Is there a way to move a bunch of files that got extracted into individual directories into the parent directly easily, or do I have to move each one individually?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? What kind of files?

Comment: Windows 10, I can't disclose the file types for confidentiality/legal reasons... but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Even your file extensions are confidential? You should put that hard disk in a safe.

Comment: there is a safe copy...in an undisclosed location.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there are no duplicate filenames?

Comment: @CharlesBurge there shouldn't be.

Comment: Well, you would want to be sure before proceeding, since you could end up overwriting files if there are duplicate names.  Anyway, this is a very non-elegant solution, but you could use the command-line version of 7-zip (7za.exe) to make an archive, and then extract it using the "e" option.  The "x" option will preserve the directory structure during extraction, but the "e" option will extract all files to the target directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files have common extension, you can use the search box to show all of them. Just search for extension prefixed with `*.`, for example `*.jpg` or `*.html`:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer showing search results]

Then just select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), cut them and paste in one folder.

If there's more than one extension, you can search for `*.*`. It will find all files with dots in filenames, so as long as your folder names don't contain dots it should work fine.

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a command line, open up Command prompt, and type:

```
for /R c:\source %f in (*.*) do copy "%f" x:\destination\
```

Replacing "Source" with the path of your parent folder, And replacing "x:\destination" with the path where you want to store the files.